# How faker generate a yaml list that browser understand?

Tags: python, yaml, faker

I've sent request use POST method

```
response = user.post(url , data)
```

here is the YAML data:

---

```
description: "{{text}}"
tags: 
  - "{{tags}}"
private: true
background: "{{background}}"
name: "{{name}}"
```

i'm using Faker for the lazy data
and here is the format:

```
    def tags(self):
        format = [
            'blue',
            'gray',
            'took a while',
            'tag, new',
            'work',
            'whatever',
            'tag',
            'truck',
            'merchant card'
            ]
        return self.random_element(format)
```

And this is the data after I rendered

```
{'tags': '-"work"', 'private': True, 'background': 'black', 'name': 'Mr. Shayne Sauer', 'description': 'Architecto quod laudantium corporis ex voluptatibus dolorem sint nisi. Id maiores reiciendis sequi. Non non qui nulla rerum non veniam.'}
```

here is the response after sent request

```
'{"_status": "ERR", "_issues": {"tags": "must be of list type"}, "_error": {"message": "Insertion failure: 1 document(s) contain(s) error(s)", "code": 422}}'
```

My question is how to render YAML data to a list??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a space between your `-` and the subsequent value. You want this:

```yaml
tags: 
  - "{{tags}}"
```

...or just:

```yaml
tags: [ "{{tags}}" ]
```

Comment: It's really hard to read code in comments. Please edit your question. As I said above, you need a space between the `-` and first `"`.

Comment: without space between the - and the subsequent value, it rise the Error Syntax 

`

    yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning a simple key
      in "<unicode string>", line 4, column 3:
          -"{{tags}}" 
          ^
    could not found expected ':'


`
the second way, it's not parse

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote. And as I wrote, the solution is to put a space there.

Comment: tks for your help, but it still not parse the value that i want to render, "put a space there" will not parse

Comment: Please edit your question to include the changes you've made.

Comment: I put a space there, it still not parse @Jordan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101031/discussion-between-khue-bui-and-jordan).

Comment: Okay, well, without seeing the code you have now and the YAML it renders or the data structure parsed from it I really can't help you.

Comment: hi, i've edited the code in the question above, i just change in tags as you said, but it not work